# do nothing more than syntax highlighting when spacemacs open python file(or any other source files)

Tags: spacemacs, python

I use spacemacs. Currently, when I open a python file, emacs will do a lot of things, it will check the syntax and give tips. This is what `describe-mode` gives:

```
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Bug-Reference-Prog Clean-Aindent Column-Number
Editorconfig Eldoc Electric-Pair Eval-Sexp-Fu-Flash Evil Evil-Escape Evil-Local
Evil-Matchit Evil-Surround Eyebrowse File-Name-Shadow Flycheck Flycheck-Pos-Tip
Font-Lock Global-Anzu Global-Auto-Revert Global-Eldoc Global-Evil-Surround
Global-Flycheck Global-Font-Lock Global-Hl-Line Global-Hl-Todo
Global-Page-Break-Lines Global-Spacemacs-Leader-Override Global-Undo-Tree
Global-Vi-Tilde-Fringe Goto-Address-Prog Hi-Lock Highlight-Numbers
Highlight-Parentheses Hl-Todo Hs Ido-Vertical Line-Number Marginalia Menu-Bar
Override-Global Persp Projectile Pupo Purpose Pyvenv-Tracking Rainbow-Delimiters
Recentf Save-Place Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Spaceline-Helm Spaceline-Info
Spacemacs-Leader-Override Sphinx-Doc Tab-Bar Tex-Pdf Transient-Mark
Treemacs-Filewatch Treemacs-Follow Treemacs-Fringe-Indicator Undo-Tree Vertico
Vi-Tilde-Fringe Volatile-Highlights Which-Key Windmove Winner Winum Xterm-Mouse
Yas Yas-Global
```

As you can see, flycheck is enabled.

But I do not need anything more than syntax highlighting. So I want to find a way to disable functions I do no need so that emacs can open a file faster, currently it takes seconds to open a python file.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of something like Spacemacs is to turn on all the features for you, so that you don’t have to hunt them down individually and configure them. Try just running Emacs with no configuration at all; it will probably be closer to what you want.